# Recursive value xxx needs type in Scala

Tags: scala, type-inference

I am confused about why Scala is complaining about this code. I have two classes which depend on each other. When I try to create a new instance of `A` without a type declaration, the code won't compile.

```scala
  class A( b:B ) {

  }

  class B( a:A ){

  }

  val y = new A ( new B( y ) ); // gives recursive value y needs type

  val z:A = new A ( new B( y ) ); // ok
```

Why does the compiler does not know the type of `y` when I declared as `new A`
?

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, should the last line not also be `val y:A = new A (new B(y));` ? I'm a little confused why that `z` is there.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To infer the type of `y`, the compiler must first determine the type of value on the right side of assignment. While evaluating right hand's type, it encounters reference to variable `y` which is (at this moment) still of unknown type. Thus the compiler detects a cycle "type of `y` dependes on type of `y`" and fails.

In the second example, this situation doesn't occur because when evaluating type of `new A(new B(y))`, it already knows the type of `y` and succeeds.

*Edit*: when the type of recursively used variable `y` needs to include a mixed-in trait, it can be declared like this:

```
val y : A with Mixin = new A(new B(y)) with Mixin
```

Comment: But this would make it impossible to mixin a trait when i have to declare the type of **y** because y would be always of type A and never sees the trait methods. I would  have to cast it all the time!

Comment: If you mean adding mixin to A, then you should be able to do `y:A with Mixin = new A(new B(y)) with Mixin`

Comment: Oh i did miss the with in the declaration

Comment: Thx so much that fixed my issue

Comment: It it fixed your issue, could you please accept the answer?

Answer (score 4):

You can specify the type of `y` specifically and it will compile:

```
 val y : A = new A(new B(y))
```