# Getting the maximum value of a column in an Apache Spark Dataframe (Scala)

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm trying to get the maximum value in a column, and wrote the below code.

```
val max = df.withColumn("max", lit(df.agg(max($"id")).as[Int].first))
```

Unfortunately, when I run it, I get the following error:

```
error: recursive value max needs type
val max = df.withColumn("max", lit(df.agg(max($"id")).as[Int].first))
```

I don't really understand what the error is telling me and I can't find any good documentation on this function. Am I writing this incorrectly? Or perhaps there is a better way to do this? I've been trying to get concrete examples but nothing seems to be working for me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Recursive value xxx needs type in Scala](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32227092/recursive-value-xxx-needs-type-in-scala)

Comment: Why do you use the `withColumn`?

Comment: @Lamanus I wanted to ultimately add the value to a new column

Comment: @AMC While that doesn't answer my specific question, it does point over to the fact that I was using the Scala Max function and not the Apache Spark Max function, as pointed out in the Accepted answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your code, the spark max was being mistaken for scala max, so I just specified the max to be from spark.

That will give you the max of id column as an integer value:

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val max = df.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max(col("id"))).collect()(0)(0).asInstanceOf[Int]

Output: max: Int = 6
```

OR

If you want to create column to store max value of id:

```
%scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
df.withColumn("max", lit(df.agg(org.apache.spark.sql.functions.max($"id")).as[Int].first))
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, I think this will work, but what exactly does the collect()(0)(0) function do?

Comment: it just collects the first value of the first element back to driver node, cuz initally i thought u just wanted the value. you could use first() instead for that